# Cloudformation: Reference Created Subnets in ElastiCache SubnetGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache, aws-cloudformation

I'm having a challenge creating an ElastiCache SubnetGroup which dynamically references the correct subnets. I'd like to use the same template in both the east and west region so I'm specifying the subnets for the subnet group in mappings. However, when I attempt to run update my stack, I get the following error:

```
Value of property SubnetIds must be of type List of String
```

Here's a gist showing roughly what i am trying to do: https://gist.github.com/brockhaywood/b71ed34c6a554a0a0fec

This unanswered question on the AWS forums appears to be a very similar problem: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=532454

Answer (score 0):

I think [`SubnetIds` should be an array](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-subnetgroup.html), where you have a single object.

```
"ElastiCacheSubnetGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "SubnetIds": [
        {
            "Fn::FindInMap":["RegionMap", { "Ref":"AWS::Region" }, AppSubnets" ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh really? the 'AppSubnets' reference is an array of Refs, would that not satisfy the need for that to be an array?

Comment: A reasonable person might think so, but it is giving you an error message complaining about the data type :).

Comment: I have tried that as well, providing the following to SubnetIds but it produces the same error:

  "SubnetIds": [{
          "Fn::FindInMap":[
          "RegionMap",
          {
            "Ref":"AWS::Region"
          },
          "AppSubnets"
          ]
        }]

Answer (score 0):

The specific issue is that you can't use `Ref` within a `Mappings` value, as noted in the [Mappings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html) documentation:

> You cannot include parameters, pseudo parameters, or intrinsic functions in the Mappings section.

As an alternative, you can use [Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) to accomplish what your template is attempting. Here's a complete working example:

[image: Launch Stack]

```
{
  "Description": "Create an ElastiCache SubnetGroup with different subnet depending on the current AWS region."
  "Conditions": {
    "us-east-1": {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}, "us-east-1"]},
    "us-west-2": {"Fn::Equals": [{"Ref":"AWS::Region"}, "us-west-2"]}
  },
  "Resources": {
    "VPC": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
      "Properties": {
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16"
      }
    },
    "AppSubnetA": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
        "AvailabilityZone": {"Fn::Select": [1, {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
      }
    },
    "AppSubnetB": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
      "Properties": {
        "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
        "CidrBlock": "10.0.1.0/24",
        "AvailabilityZone": {"Fn::Select": [1, {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]}
      }
    },
    "ElastiCacheSubnetGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "SubnetGroup",
        "SubnetIds": {"Fn::If": ["us-east-1", [
            {"Ref": "AppSubnetA"}
          ],
          {"Fn::If": ["us-west-2",
            [
              {"Ref": "AppSubnetB"}
            ],
            {"Ref":"AWS::NoValue"}
          ]}
        ]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's not possible to use dynamic values in Mappings section of CloudFormation template.